# blob image always the same size and displaying not the full image

Tags: javascript, php

I'm posting a blob to php via jquery with the following code.

```
var blob = dataURLToBlob(dataURL);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    // this function is triggered once a call to readAsDataURL returns
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('data', event.target.result);
        $.post("upload.php",{data: fd},
    function(data,status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
    };      
    // trigger the read from the reader...
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

upload.php

```
// pull the raw binary data from the POST array
$data = substr($_POST['data'], strpos($_POST['data'], ",") + 1);
// decode it
$decodedData = base64_decode($data);
// print out the raw data, 
echo ($decodedData);
$timestamp = date('YmdHis');
$fileName = ''.$timestamp.'.png';
file_put_contents($fileName, $decodedData);
```

I'm not getting the data from a database it comes directly from my "signature pad" and then saving the image to folder. When I display my image via window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); the image is correct but the uploaded image only display a quarter to half of the image.

I have noticed that the images are always the same size (2KB) and my php settings for upload files and post size are both on 40MB.

Any thoughts on why my images are always the same size, thus uploading only maybe half the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `max_input_vars` in your `php.ini` file to a larger number.